# jQuery Datepicker - Exclude certain days, but allow specific dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to exclude Monday and Tuesday from a datepicker throughout the year, but need to allow this during the holiday season for 2020-12-21 and 2020-12-22.

How could I counter the `day != 1 && day != 2` and only use this if not one of the above dates?

```
var excludeDates = ["2020-12-24","2020-12-25","2020-12-26","2020-12-27","2020-12-28","2020-12-29","2020-12-30","2020-12-31","2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03",,"2021-01-04","2021-01-05","2021-01-06"];

$( function() {
  $( "#roves_collection_date" ).datepicker({
    minDate : advanceCollection,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      return [(day != 1 && day != 2 && excludeDates.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add another array for dates to *include* (overwrite any excludes) then you can use:

```
return [((day != 1 && day != 2 && excludeDates.indexOf(string) == -1) 
        || includeDates.indexOf(string) >= 0)];
```

```js
var excludeDates = ["2020-12-24", "2020-12-25", "2020-12-26", "2020-12-27", "2020-12-28", "2020-12-29", "2020-12-30", "2020-12-31", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", , "2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06"];
var includeDates = ["2020-12-21", "2020-12-22"];

$(function() {
  $("#dte").datepicker({
    //minDate: advanceCollection,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      console.log(day, string, includeDates.indexOf(string));
      return [((day != 1 && day != 2 && excludeDates.indexOf(string) == -1) 
              || includeDates.indexOf(string) >= 0)];
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='dte' />
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, although dates within the excludeDates array do need to be excluded as the store will be shut.

The ones that should be included are the 2020-12-21 and 2020-12-22 as these fall on Monday/Tuesday, which are excluded throughout the year, but should be selectable in this case - is this achievable?

Comment: Updated following clarification of which dates are to be included